# Will using es2017 as a lib in my tsconfig but having es5 as my target render my code incompatible with IE11?

Tags: ecmascript-5, tsconfig, ecmascript-2017

My code needs to be able to support IE11 at the minimum, which renders most ES6+ modules incompatible. I've set the target in my tsconfig to es5, however I wanted to use es2017 modules in my code. Will adding es2017 into my libs and using its modules break my site's IE11 compatibility?

I looked all over the internet and I'm finding it hard to nail down a solid definition of what a target vs the libs are in the tsconfig and how they affect browser compatibility.